# How to set the timeout of test in dart's unittest?

Tags: dart, dart-async, dart-unittest

Is it possible to set the max time that a test can run? Just like:

```dart
@Test(timeout=1000)
public void testSomething() {}
```

in jUnit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the following line in the `main()` of you tests

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  useHtmlEnhancedConfiguration(); // (or some other configuration setting)
  unittestConfiguration.timeout = new Duration(seconds: 3); // <<== add this line

  test(() {
    // do some tests
  });
}
```

You could easily setup a time guard using `setUp()` and `tearDown()` and a `Timer`

```dart
library x;

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  group("some group", () {
    Timer timeout;
    setUp(() {
      // fail the test after Duration
      timeout = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1), () => fail("timed out"));
    });

    tearDown(() {
        // if the test already ended, cancel the timeout
        timeout.cancel();
    });

    test("some very slow test", () {
      var callback = expectAsync0((){});
      new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
        expect(true, equals(true));
        callback();
      });
    });

    test("another very slow test", () {
      var callback = expectAsync0((){});
      new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
        expect(true, equals(true));
        callback();
      });
    });


    test("a fast test", () {
      var callback = expectAsync0((){});
      new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
        expect(true, equals(true));
        callback();
      });
    });

  });
}
```

this fails the entire group, but groups can be nested, therefore you have full control what tests should be watched for timeouts.

Comment: That's a global setting for all tests, right? Currently we can't set the timeout for a specified test.

Comment: @Freewind I added an example of a per test timeout. Works so far, don't know if there are situations where it doesn't. Just invented it ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can put this line of code above your import statements now to determine your test timeout time.

```
@Timeout(const Duration(seconds: 45))
```

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test#timeouts

Comment: This answer is a much better practice than using a Timer.

Comment: Now, this approach breaks the `invalid_annotation_target` linter rule. It says `The annotation 'Timeout' can only be used on libraries`.